# Phonegap using Windows Mobile app, how to give the full path of the images in CSS file?

Tags: css, cordova, windows-mobile

I am developing the windows mobile app using Phonegap or Cordova framework using. I place the CSS file some of the background images like

```
footer ul li {
float: left;
padding: 5% 10.9%;
background: url(./img/tabs.png) top left no-repeat; 
}
```

This above CSS file I am using in different places. But it is not loading proper manner. Some pages images are missing. Some pages images are displaying.

How to place the full image path in the CSS file? I placing the Android "file:///android_asset/www/images/tabs.png". In Windows, how to place the full path in the CSS file?

Answer (score 0):

it would be the Build Action of your image file is incorrect.

To change the Build Action right click a file and choose properties to go to the properties window if you do not already have it open. It is probably then the first property. Just click and choose the correct one.

For anyone following along, to change a file from Resource to Content:

- In Solution Explorer, navigate to the file.
- Multi-select (control-click) all image files (.png, .jpg, etc)
- Alt-Enter, or right-click -> Properties
- Build Action: in the combo/drop down, choose Content.
- Deploy project.

Comment: @vicky I m also talking abt phonegap app